# Explanation of 1 commit ahead of master and 1 commit behind master

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I just updated my branch on GitHub with a push. I wanted to add some files that were taken out before.  After the merge, my work should match the work on the master branch and everything on both branches should be up to date, but it still says "1 commit behind master". I also saw my branch was ahead of the master before.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Did you happen to pull before doing anything?  Is someone else working in your repository (including you with another machine) and has made a change to the remote?

Comment: Yes. I pulled from the master branch to get the recent updated commits made by the other team members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot push anything that hasn't been committed yet. The order of operations is:

> Make your change.
>
> `git add` - this stages your changes for committing
>
> `git commit` - this commits your staged changes locally
>
> `git push` - this pushes your committed changes to a remote

If you push without committing, nothing gets pushed. If you commit without adding, nothing gets committed. If you add without committing, nothing at all happens, git merely remembers that the changes you added should be considered for the following commit.

The message you're seeing (your branch is ahead by 1 commit) means that your local repository has one commit that hasn't been pushed yet.

In other words: add and commit are local operations, push, pull and fetch are operations that interact with a remote.